# Replace content specific HTML tag using PHP

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I have HTML code:

```
<div>
   <h1>Header</h1>
   <code><p>First code</p></code>
   <p>Next example</p>
   <code><b>Second example</b></code>
</div>
```

Using PHP I want replace all `<` symbols located in `code` elements for example above code I want converted to:

```
<div>
   <h1>Header</h1>
   <code>&lt;p>First code&lt;/p></code>
   <p>Next example</p>
   <code>&lt;b>Second example&lt;/b></code>
</div>
```

I try using PHP `DomDocument` class but my work was ineffective. Below is my code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content);

$innerHTML= '';
$tmp = '';
if(count($dom->getElementsByTagName('*'))){
    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('*') as $child) {

        if($child->tagName == 'code'){
            $tmp = $child->ownerDocument->saveXML( $child);
            $innerHTML .= htmlentities($tmp);
        }
        else{
            $innerHTML .= $child->ownerDocument->saveXML($child);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is you `Dom Document` code?

Comment: @AbraCadaver  I add my Dom Document code in below answer.

Answer (score 0):

So, you're iterating over the markup properly, and your use of `saveXML()` was close to what you want, but nowhere in your code do you try to actually change the contents of the element. This should work:

```
<?php
$content='<div>
   <h1>Header</h1>
   <code><p>First code</p></code>
   <p>Next example</p>
   <code><b>Second example</b></code>
</div>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('code') as $child) {
    // get the markup of the children
    $html = implode(array_map([$child->ownerDocument,"saveHTML"], iterator_to_array($child->childNodes)));
    // create a node from the string
    $text = $dom->createTextNode($html);
    // remove existing child nodes
    foreach ($child->childNodes as $node) {
        $child->removeChild($node);
    }
    // append the new text node - escaping is done automatically
    $child->appendChild($text);
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, code works great. I have question: how I can change this code to make <code> tag inside <pre> tag?